# How to by pass super key cord to system?

Tags: osx

I am using emacs25 on macOS.

How to bypass command key cord, e.g., ctrl-command-/ to system?

Currently it is captured by emacs.

Answer (score 2):

The OS examines all events to see which application to send them to. If the OS is going to handle a keyboard event, it'll do so at that time and not notify any applications.

Comment: i feel it's the contrary.  emacs tells the OS, do not handle the keys, let me handle it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your feeling is wrong. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I set the keystroke ctrl+cmd+/ to toggle the display of menubar. (I've set macOS to automatically hide the menubar).  https://imgur.com/a/b1quL

Comment: If emacs is seeing the key chord, then the OS has already passed it on. Have you confirmed the format of the key combination?  I assume you are setting it via System Preferences under the Apple menu?